# Elasticsearch aggregation over timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-api

I'm having the following document in ElasticSearch:

```
"ipAddress": "192.168.10.12", "timestamp": "25 Oct 2015 20:00:00", "switchovers": 2

"ipAddress": "192.168.10.12", "timestamp": "26 Oct 2015 20:00:00", "switchovers": 1
```

How can I write an elasticsearch aggregation to find out switchovers[today] - switchovers[yesterday] grouped by IP address?

This is where i'm at:

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
  "match_all": {}
},
    "aggs": {
      "switchover_count_over_time": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "ipAddress"
        },
      }
  }
}'
```

Yet to figure out how to extract switchovers for each date (from oct. for example) and compute the difference from the previous day's switchover value..

Any help?

Comment: You won't be able to compute the difference. You will need to handle this in your app.

Comment: Can't I make use of [scripting aggregation feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) here?

Comment: Perhaps you can. But I find it better to handle this in your app code rather than Elastic. That's just my opinion.

Comment: The thing which restricts me from computing this logic outside is that ultimately we want to write similar aggregations on the fly without relying on any app.. And visualize this result in Kibana if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use date histogram aggregation on a date/timestamp field.Here is the linkhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html.Add a terms aggregation on ipaddress/switchovers inside the date_histogram aggregation.

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "date_interval" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            }, "aggs": {
              "switch_over": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "ip/switchovers",
                  "size": 100
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.